# Static string factory

Tags: c#

I am relatively new to C# and I am trying to make a static class where I can store some urls as strings in this manner:

```
namespace ServerUrls
{
    public static class ServerUrls
    {
        public static string serverUrl { get { return "https://url"; } }
    }
}
```

and then I want to call it on my Http Request like this:

```
using ServerUrls
...
var result = await serverUrl
```

But this doesn't work. Is this a wrong a approach and what am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

I am using flurl for my http Request like this:

```
public async Task<List<myList>> GetList()
    {
        var result = await "https://myserver.com"
            .AppendPathSegments()
```

And this works I just want to store my urls on a separate class

Comment: Currently it's not possible to `await` a *string* in c#. Only something awaitable such as `Task`

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? Await says "call this thing in an asynchronous manner". And you're trying to await a string. What does calling a string in an asynchronous manner do?

Comment: That string is essentially a compilation constant. Why do you want a "factory" for it and why are you using `await`?

Comment: If you want to make an HTTP call, use a class that makes HTTP calls. `await` has nothing to do with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you added that you're using [Flurl](https://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/) it is clearer what you want to achieve (and that you don't want to await on string but on task that is being created by the chain of extension methods from that library).

You can use that URL from your `ServerUrls` class in `GetList()` simply by replacing that hardcoded URL:

```
var result = await ServerUrls.serverUrl
                   .AppendPathSegments()
                   ...
```

It would be even better if you make `GetList()` more flexible by adding a `string` argument to it and then pass desired URL from `ServerUrls` to it:

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetList(string url)
{
    var result = await url
                       .AppendPathSegments()
                       ...
}
```

Also, make sure you have the right return type as `Task<List<myList>>` doesn't make sense - replace `myList` with desired type (e.g. `string`).

Comment: That's what I was trying to do but it doesn't work: ServerUrls.serverurl

Comment: What is the error you get? Try first to rename either namespace or class - they should not have same names (`ServerUrls`).

Comment: "The type or namespace serverurl does not exist in the namespace". Both my namespace and class have a different name.

Comment: In the code snippet you posted in the question they do - they are both named `ServerUrls`. Also, can you show the line of code where this error occurs?

Comment: My mistake, I thought you meant different namespace on the http request class. I changed the namesace from ServerUrls and now it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prefix the field with the class name if you are not in the same class...

so for example `ServerUrls.serverUrl`

Also you will have to use HttpClient or something to download the url;

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string reply = client.DownloadString(ServerUrls.serverUrl);
Console.WriteLine(reply);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the name of the class AND the name of the string you need.

So you will do

```
var string = ServerUrls.serverUrl;
```

And as Fabjan specified in the comments, you will have to do some workaround to use a `HttpClient` to do your request.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use properties for string constants, because C# lets you create named string constants with syntax specifically designed for that purpose:

```
public class CommonUrls {
    public const string Server = "https://url";
}
```

Now you can use this constant as follows:

```
using (var client = new WebClient()) {
    var bytes = await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(CommonUrls.Server);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect it to know that you want to make a HTTP request to that string just because it's formatted as such. Your compiler just looks at it as a string, not a URL.

So, you'll have to use something else to make requests such as the `HttpClient` native to the .NET Framework:

```
public async void MakeRequest()
{
    var http = new HttpClient();
    var response = await http.GetAsync(ServerUrls.serverUrl);
    response.EnsureStatusSuccessCode(); //Throws an exception if status code isn't 200.
    var html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to dispose `HttpClient` as it implements `IDisposable`.